# What's the difference between "module self::X" and "module X"?

Tags: ruby

How is

`module self::GenName`

different from simply

`module GenName`

Note that this module is nested inside another module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since

```
module M1
  puts "self = #{self}"
  module self::GenName
    puts Module.nesting
    def self.gen_name
    end
  end
end
  # self = M1
  # M1::GenName
  # M1
```

we see that `M1` is the same as

```
module M1
  module M1::GenName
    puts Module.nesting
    def self.gen_name
    end
  end
end
  # M1::GenName
  # M1
```

which should come as no surprise. `GenName` is referenced (for example)

```
M1::GenName.methods(false)
  #=> [:gen_name]
```

in both cases. If we instead write

```
module M2
  module GenName
    puts Module.nesting
    def self.gen_name
    end
  end
end
  # M2::GenName
  # M2
```

then

```
M2::GenName.methods(false)
  #=> [:gen_name]
```

This shows that Ruby references `GenName` the same way in both cases. I'm convinced there's no difference if `self.` is added, but I also think the above falls short of a proof.

Comment: It's true. Adding `self::` is almost always pointless, and the occasions where it is strictly required are so obscure I'm not sure I can think of one.